# Deploy virtual PC based on snapshot using Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, deployment, snapshot

I have a server with Hyper-V configured, it is easy to create a new virtual machine using the management tools, but it can take some time.

I often see those hosts that say "We can have your server ready in 5 seconds". And I wonder how do they manage this? I would also like to deploy a full functional clean server in 5 seconds.

So how is this done? Is it by first installing a clean server, then take a snapshot of that for later to deploy a new server based on that snapshot?

I tried doing this, but I did not find any where to install a new virtual machine based on the snapshot.

Anyone got any thoughts to share on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is done by creating a Virtual Machine Template, this is a VM that you have configured the way you want all your VM's to be and you then replicate each time you want to create a new VM. This means you don't have to go through a complete install of Windows every time you create a VM.

However, it's not as simple as just copying the machine, as you end up with issues like duplicate SIDS, machine names, IP addresses etc. [This article](http://sondreb.com/blog/post/Hyper-V-Making-Template-Virtual-Machines.aspx) provides a very brief overview of how to create template VM's, [this article](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/general-virtualization-articles/cloning-hyper-v-virtual-machines-right-way-part1.html) goes a bit more in depth into the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need SCCM.

What you can do is:

- Script the creation of a virtual machien
- Start with a copy of a prepard image.

Basically:

- Install an image once
- make a differential disc
- On it make  sysprep that does not remove drivers.

Then, on the new machine:

- start with a copy of said disc

Creating a new machine is trivial with powershell (http://poshcode.org/571). Really takes only one second, and you just need 2 parameters: number cpu's and amount ram.

The copy starts and should be ready within - hm - a minute or so. maximum.

This is at least what I do ;) No snapshots here for that ;)